# How to detect new line or tab characters (\n or \t) while reading unformatted stream files?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm reading a file into a character string like this:

```
character*50, intent(in) :: flname
character(len=:), allocatable :: str
integer size

inquire(file=flname, size=size)  
allocate(character(len=size)::str)              

open(1, file=flname, status='OLD', access='STREAM') 
read(1) str
close(1)
```

I'm trying to loop over the character string and detect certain characters, including ones like the new line ('\n') or tab ('\t') characters. But for some reason, I cannot detect those characters in a file. Is Fortran automatically ignoring these characters and if so, how can I get it to detect them?

Comment: Please show your loop and detection effort, so that we can debug.

Comment: You claim you cannot detect the characters but you do not show how you try to detect them.

Comment: The attempt is in the cross-post https://fortran-lang.discourse.group/t/reading-new-line-or-tab-characters-from-file/5544/4  I suggest to not cross-post immmediately. Many people visit both of these sites. You can wait an hour or two and if there no responses, do cross-post. This is just wasting time of the people tryimg to help when you already have the solution on the other site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to directly compare with previously-specified characters, e.g. NL, CR, HT in the code below.

```
program test
   integer i
   character, parameter :: NL = new_line( 'A' )             ! new line
   character, parameter :: CR = achar( 13 )                 ! carriage return
   character, parameter :: HT = achar(  9 )                 ! horizontal tab
   character(len=50) :: flname = "test.f90"
   character(len=:), allocatable :: str
   integer size

   inquire(file=flname, size=size)
   allocate(character(len=size)::str)
   open( 1, file=flname, status='OLD', access='STREAM' )
   read(1) str
   close(1)

   do i = 1, size
      select case( str(i:i) )
         case( NL ); write(*,*) "New line"
         case( CR ); write(*,*) "Carriage return"
         case( HT ); write(*,*) "Horizontal tab"
         case default; write(*,*) "Letter [", str(i:i), "]"
      end select
   end do

end program test
```